# Custom dialog won't dispose when dispose is called

Tags: java, dialog, codenameone

So I'm very new to Codename One and I was trying out the Dialog class.
When I create the Dialog it shows the Buttons and the text but when I want to dipose it, it won't disappear.
Any suggestions?

```
private void createDialog(String title) {

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(title);
    dialog.add("You ended the game.");
    dialog.add("Choose what to do");
    Button stay = new Button("Stay");
    Button newGame = new Button("New Game");
    Button menu = new Button("Menu");

    dialog.add(stay);
    dialog.add(menu);
    dialog.add(newGame);
    dialog.show();
    dialog.dispose();

     if(stay.isToggle()){
        //
     }

  }
```

I'm expecting a dialogbox with 3 buttons, 2 text.
Then to dispose when I call the method.
Also another question is the isToogle the right method to call, when I want something to happen if I click on the button?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `dispose()` method immediately after `show()`, which is wrong as it will attempt to dispose the dialog right after showing it.

Also, to add click event to a button, call `addActionListener()`.

```
private void createDialog(String title) {

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(title);
    dialog.add("You ended the game.");
    dialog.add("Choose what to do");
    Button stay = new Button("Stay");
    Button newGame = new Button("New Game");
    Button menu = new Button("Menu");

    dialog.add(stay);
    dialog.add(menu);
    dialog.add(newGame);
    dialog.show();

    stay.addActionListener(evt -> {
         dialog.dispose();
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this method, also the same with a Thread.sleep between didn't function neither, got any idea?

Comment: You should never call thread sleep as this would block the EDT. Also make sure you invoke this method exactly once in a row. if you invoke this method twice the dialog will dispose and go back to the previous dialog.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Hello Shai 

Didn't work either...I'm currently working with the mediaplayer in the GUI Builder, how can I put there a video form the Data section?

Comment: What's "data section"?